# Rating calculation

Tags: rating

Maybe is a dumb question but I'm figthing with a rating calculation. I've a global rating which is between 0 and 1, the number of ratings, the user rating.

How can I calculate the new rating with :

- the old global rating
- the user rating
- the new and old number of ratings

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: What datatype are you using to store your global rating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Multiply the previous average rating by the previous number of
  ratings.
- Add the new rating.
- Divide by the previous number of ratings plus
  one to get the new average.

Careful with your choice of data types or you will lose a little accuracy each time you do this calculation.

Pseudocode:

```
newRating = ((oldRating * previousNumberOfRatings) + userRating) / (previousNumberOfRatings + 1)
```